# Is there any possibilty to delete old chat messages containing sensitive information?

Tags: support, chat

I know a similar question has been asked multiple times but my scenario is unique:

In one of my chat rooms, which is around 2-3 years old, I have accidentally posted sensitive information.

I have a deadline of 2 days to delete this information. 
Is there anyway that I can get it deleted immediately?

Note: I have like 1000 entries with sensitive information. Raising a flag will take a lot of time. Is it possible to delete the whole chatroom instead?

Comment: Just raise a custom mod flag on one of your posts pointing to the message in the chat transcript you want deleted. Or raise a chat mod flag on one of your recent chat messages linking to the message you want deleted.

Comment: i have reported multiple messages . now i am getting "You have fully used your vote allowance for today" what should i do ?

Comment: All you can do now is have patience. In theory you could use the contact us link at the bottom of any page but SE is not a 24/7 shop so they will at best attend to it at the earliest of Monday EST working hours, assuming not more pressing issues are in the queue. Yours is not an issue they would consider a priority.

Comment: @rene thanks for your answer : but i will  be under legal action and i am in shock and i am just desperate here.

Comment: @rene :one question please will delete my profile will help?

Comment: That will not delete messages, no. It will annonimise the message and all your posts but will not remove them. That is because of the legal agreement you have with SE once you created an account and decided to post content.

Comment: @rene thanks for your replies. How do you see it now? I flag the messages daily and they will delete them? All i need here is time right?

Comment: Just a note, but all the sensitive information you are discussing is available in the public Stack Exchange archive in the form of many of your posts before your revisions 14 hours ago (revealing the company you work at, the backend URL for the program you are working on, etc). Although CC-by-SA 3.0 allows a certain level of redaction, lawyers _can't_ force you to remove everything in two days, or ever.

Comment: @forest: yes even i found it on google when i search with specific information. how long does it take to update on google ? Am i totally screwed here ? or do i still have some options.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "screwed". Will your company react if _anything_ is available anywhere? I mean if they search for archives or even click post revisions, they'll see the name of your company (or at least information leading to it). But as far as I could tell, the only sensitive things you redacted were keywords relating to the name of your company and the word "blueberry" (which I still haven't figured out yet). It doesn't seem to me like the mere name of your company in a keyword would make a lawyer upset.

Comment: @forest : they said i have to take all the post down / delete which have info related to company and for that i have 2 days of time (1 left). I dont know if i should immediately search lawyer for me or not.

Comment: @forest i am still able to search on google with particular keywords though when i open the post it is not there but google search is showing data. do you know how much time does it take for google to update the search.

Comment: Google might take a number of hours or a day, depending on how active the question is. I think you should search for a lawyer (depending on what the penalty is if you don't get it removed in 2 days), yes.

Comment: @forest thanks, will do that. Some lessons are learned hard way.

Comment: Indeed. Next time, don't post company data with original keywords under your own name. :P

Comment: i thank you moderators and community members who took there time to help and guide me.I highly appreciate that.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, [you can never fully delete something on the Internet](https://www.quora.com/Ive-heard-people-say-that-you-can-never-permanently-delete-things-from-the-internet-so-watch-what-you-say-and-or-do-How-does-that-whole-theory-work). It's something that you should definitely tell the person who gave you the deadline.

That said, [@rene's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317737/is-there-any-possible-to-delete-the-old-chat-containing-sensitive-informationi#comment1042057_317737) is probably the way to go: if you'd like to flag something on Stack Exchange but can't because there's no UI for it, flag something else (related to you or to the content you want to flag) and specify **very clearly** which content is causing problems. In this particular case, it's probably easier for moderators to delete the entire chatroom, especially if it's 2-3 years old and not active anymore. Given that sometimes [rooms are deleted automatically](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention), it's a valid request.

---

If you have only one or two old messages with sensitive information and you're feeling hacky, it *is* possible to raise a moderator chat flag (the one you usually need for this type of request) for older chat messages, even though the UI doesn't support it.

Navigate to the chat message in the transcript. You can find out the ID of the message by hovering over it (or use the 'permalink' from the popup):

[image]

Copy the following text into a text editor:

```
$.post('https://<chat server>/messages/<message id>/mod', { info: "<your message>", fkey: fkey().fkey });
```

and replace `<chat server>` with the domain (`chat.stackexchange.com` for most chatrooms, this example message was taken from the Tavern on the Meta which resides on `chat.meta.stackexchange.com`), and `<message id>` with the ID you just obtained. Replace `<your message>` with the content of your flag message (be sure not to use double quotes or escape them; newlines probably won't work either).

Open the console of your browser and execute it. If you made a mistake, you'll probably get a 500 Internal Server Error; if not, it should work:

[image]

♦ moderators can directly delete the message from the flag handling UI (though they should also purge the history of the message if they want to redact sensitive information).

Comment: thanks for your response and this method for a particular message. in my case i have probably 1000 messages where i have used the sensitive information and i can only flag limited messages i believe around 25-30. I have raised ticket per email i hope they will take some action.can i use another account (request my friend) to set the flag? Since i have per day limit.?

Comment: the post request did not get execute. it responds with 404. it can be since its Frozen room and quite old.

Comment: In your case it's clearly better to use *one* flag requesting the room to be deleted.

Comment: thanks for your response. my last question since i have raised many flags  and getting following message "You have fully used your vote allowance for today" Can i use another account to raise the flags and properly describe in Flag message ?

Comment: @Roxy using second accounts to do anything you can't do with a single account is considered abuse, so no, you shouldn't use another account. You run the risk having all accounts suspended, not allowing you do anything at all for a serious amount of time.

Comment: @rene thanks for your reply. Then will wait.

Comment: @Roxy I've deleted that room and marked it as private leaving a note in the room as to why... that'll prevent non-mods access to the room even if people know it's there... Can't do anything about what might have "escaped" until now though

Comment: @jon clements thanks a lot. I have raised flag in 3-4 other rooms as well. Could you please have a look into that as well? I will highly appreciate that.

Comment: @something - actually, the "you can never delete anything from the internet" meme is more true by the year. It's just that people think it is more true... Pretty scary

Comment: @Roxy are you going to be raising many more flags... this is getting a little daft now... how many rooms did you spread all this confidential information across!? :)

Comment: @JonClements extremely sorry for the inconvenience. 2 Rooms more.I will make sure i dont raise any more flags.

Comment: @JonClements i think you have already processed them . Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Roxy okay just to clarify how this works - the messages still technically exist - it's just those rooms (unless archived else where) aren't accessible/searchable/etc... by anyone except SO moderators/staff now... you won't be able to access them again either... That's pretty much all that can be done...

Comment: @JonClements ok thanks for the info and thanks for your effort.